# How can I move a fragment and resize it

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I see on Gmail app. When user touch on an email in email list. The email list is move to the left and resize. Like those of image :

[mail list](http://img546.imageshack.us/img546/7210/mail1w.png)

[mail view](http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/738/mail2k.png)

Sorry. I am a newcomers and I can't post image.
Do you know how can we do it ? Or what kind of things they are using ?

Thanks